# Ecommerce: Conversion suggestions

Tags: e-commerce

I'm a technical person with in-depth knowledge on Python and its framework. I've build an ecommerce store using Django-Oscar. I've multiple products in my store.

My store offers a large assortment of products in the Electronics category. A new and upcoming sub-category is surveillance and security systems. However, due to the varied nature of products in this category, the products are distributed across “Home Security” (Under Appliances) and “Security Systems”, etc. (under the Computers & Laptop > Office Equipment). A better understanding of the market segments is required for better positioning these products.

I reviewed [Maplin](http://www.maplin.co.uk/c/cctv-and-security), another e-store that provides same category of products on its store for better placing of my products.

Since I'm not a business analyst or a sales person, I want to get some recommendations/suggestions on how my e-commerce store can structure the  products to increase conversion based on your review of the Maplin Storefront and my own product mix in this category. The constraint is that I cannot create a separate level 1 category for surveillance and security systems.

i tried Google on where should a particular product be placed to increase the conversion rate, but to little fortune. Also, I tried finding other SO portals where this type of question is a fit, but couldn't find any. So, if you can let me know the appropriate portal for this kind of question, it will be of great help!!! You can provide your recommendation/suggestions here as well.

Thanks!!! Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- register for google webmaster tools 
  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
  -- then verify your website with google
- take a look at google merchant center
  https://www.google.com/merchants/
- this page has links to google product taxonomy docs with categories etc
  https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160081
- amazon is also worth looking at http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200218500
- next step would be structured data for the products 
  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158
- http://schema.org/Product